Align color scales of two ggplots in `geom_contour_filled()`
I'm trying to align two color scales of ggplots with geom_contour_filled. Below is a minimum example.
library(ggplot2)

df_1 <- df_2 <- data.frame(
    n = rep(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), each = 10),
    r = rep(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), 10)
)

df_1$value <- df_1$n + df_1$r

df_2$value <- df_2$n + df_2$r + 0.2

p1 <- ggplot(df_1, aes(x = n, y = r, z = value)) +
    geom_contour_filled(breaks = seq(0, 2, length.out = 21)) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")

p2 <- ggplot(df_2, aes(x = n, y = r, z = value)) +
    geom_contour_filled(breaks = seq(0, 2, length.out = 21)) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")

p1+p2


The expectation both color scales should be the same. Aligning breaks doesn't help, please do not combine two data frames, I need the freedom to use two ggplots separately.
Thanks.

You could explicitly add a fill scale, i.e. scale_fill_viridis_d, for which you set drop=FALSE to prevent unused levels from being dropped and additionally add show.legend=TRUE to geom_contour_filled (the latter is required in ggplot2 >= 3.5.0 to display a legend key for unused levels):
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(df_1, aes(x = n, y = r, z = value)) +
  geom_contour_filled(
    breaks = seq(0, 2, length.out = 21),
    show.legend = TRUE
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(drop = FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

p2 <- ggplot(df_2, aes(x = n, y = r, z = value)) +
  geom_contour_filled(
    breaks = seq(0, 2, length.out = 21),
    show.legend = TRUE
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(drop = FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

p1 + p2 +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect") &
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")


